# Subtract objects in one NSArray from another array

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, cocoa-touch, nsarray, subtraction

I have two NSArrays:

```
NSArray *wants = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"apples", 
                  @"oranges", 
                  @"pineapple", 
                  @"mango", 
                  @"strawberries", 
                  nil];
NSArray *needs = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  @"apples", 
                  @"pineapple", 
                  @"strawberries", 
                  nil];
```

And I want to `XOR` them. Something like `wants - needs` so that what I have left is

```
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
@"oranges", 
@"mango", 
nil];
```

I would normally go through some heavy looping, but I am sure there is a more practical way. What should I do instead?

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Something like this?

```
NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:wants];
[array removeObjectsInArray:needs];
```

Comment: Wont that crash if needs contains objects that dont exist in wants?

Comment: @TompaLompa No, it doesn't crash.  From the NSMutableArray docs:  `If the receiving array does not contain objects in otherArray, the method has no effect (although it does incur the overhead of searching the contents).`

Comment: This is NOT an XOR, as if needs contains an object that wants doesn't, the result will not contain that object.

Comment: Fortunately the shoe fit on this one as well and it's a very simple/slick solution. I knew there had to be a shorter way than what I was going to do..

Answer (score 9):

How about using predicates?

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF IN %@)", needs];
NSArray *wants_needs = [wants filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

Comment: Hi @Gyfis, using predicates it's reduce the half time to filter the data. Thanks for this solution.

Answer (score 8):

Kirby's answer is fine, but: if you don't care about the order of the elements in the arrays, you should be using sets instead. If the order is important, you might consider `NSOrderedSet`.  You can use the `-minusSet:` or, for the latter, `-minusOrderedSet:` methods.

Comment: This is definitely the way to go. I'm imagining order isn't important in this example, but even if it is, sets are highly optimized for this kind of behavior.

Comment: Note that `NSOrderedSet` is only available in OSX ≥ 10.7 and iOS ≥ 5.0.

Answer (score 2):

Given two assumptions: that the order is unimportant (or can be restored -- e.g., if the arrays are sorted now)* and that no item appears more than once in either array (although you can use a counted set for this), a set might be a good choice.

The XOR (strictly, the symmetric difference) of two sets is the union minus the intersection:

```
NSMutableSet * unioned = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:wants];
[unioned unionSet:[NSSet setWithArray:needs]];
NSMutableSet * intersection = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:needs];
[intersection intersectSet:[NSSet setWithArray:wants]];

[unioned minusSet:intersection];
```

---

*If order is important, you can use [`NSOrderedSet`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsorderedset?language=objc).

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
NSArray *NSArray_XOR(NSArray *arr1, NSArray *arr2)
{
    NSMutableArray *results = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i = 0; i < arr1.count; i++) {
        id obj = [arr1 objectAtIndex:i];

        if (![arr2 containsObject:obj])
            [results addObject:obj];
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr2.count; i++) {
        id obj = [arr2 objectAtIndex:i];

        if (![arr1 containsObject:obj])
            [results addObject:obj];
    }

    // make a unmutable copy of the array.
    return [NSArray arrayWithArray:results];
}
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but this algorithm is at least O(n^2) when it should be much simpler.

Comment: Yeah probably not the best way.